# Database and application design for frequent itemset generation

Tags: mysql, .net, data-mining

I'm datamining match data from an online game where each match is 5 on 5 with each player picking a unique character or hero at the start of the match.

My ultimate goal is to use frequent itemset generation to determine which hero combinations are the most popular, and potentially which combinations win more frequently.

I'd like to have an application that would be web based, where a user enters heroes chosen by the opposing team, and the heroes currently chosen by your team and recommends heroes to choose.  These heroes would be ones that show up more frequently in winning games against the heroes selected by the opposing team.

I know that heroes that are picked more frequently, will also end up showing up more frequently in winning games, which is why I may use a transaction database that only contains heroes from the game mode where heroes are chosen randomly for each player.

I have a MySQL database which has a Match table, a Hero table and a MatchHero table that contains a primary key of (MatchId,HeroId) and a bool of whether or not that hero won.  This table currently has about 26 million entries.  The problem is fetching the data can take anywhere from 3 to 14 seconds depending on the number of records (fewer user selections results in more records fetched).

What would be the best design to allow me to implement this where fetching data, and doing calculations was fast enough for a web app?  Storing the table in memory?  I'm not too worried about the actually itemset generation algorithm as I've already have had decent performance with apriori.  Could anything related to frequent itemset generation be precalculated? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use indexes for faster data access. Do as much data analysis in the database as possible to avoid copying it to your application. Reduce the number of queries, and instead use stored procedures and prepared statements.

Make sure that you *really* have understood Apriori.

If you are computing the support for each itemset with a SQL query, you are doing it wrong. Use 1 pass over the database for each itemset *length*; i.e. 1 pass for all 1-itemsets, 1 pass for all 2-itemsets, 1 pass for all 3-itemsets.

The basic idea of Apriori is not hard, but many people don't get all the details, and then it becomes much slower than necessary.